# char array used in switch statement

Tags: java, expression, constants, java-7, primitive

Why does my compiler get mad (Constant expression required) when I say:

```
final static char [] BASES = new char[]{'A', 'T', 'C', 'G'};
.
.
       char c= in.charAt(i);
            switch(c){
                case BASES[0] : break;
                case BASES[1] : packed =(char) (packed | 1); break;
                .
                .
                .
            }
```

but if I say:

```
final static char a ='A';
final static char t ='T';
         switch(c){
                case a : break;
                ...
```

it's happy?
I feel like I'm being thick here. :-/

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, the `char[]` is final, but the contents aren't. I.e. you can't say `BASES = new char[] { ... }`, but you can still say `BASES[0] = 'X';`, so `BASES[0]` is not constant.

Comment: What is the purpose if having the constants for the case of the switch statement in an array and not in seperate `static final char` constants? You don't use the array itself in the example.

Comment: I would like to use the array in a few other places as an array. It's basically making the code a little less fragile. Not a massive deal. I just felt a bit thick not being able to figure it out...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The argument to a `case` must be a constant, i.e. a primitive/string constant or literal or an enum constant. Your array is constant but not its content...

In your case, an enum would be indicated and the code below is an example of how you could write it. It puts all the logic linked to the bases in the enum which you can now reuse where you need to - you can add methods too. And the main code is now clean and easy to read.

Main code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "ATC";
    char packed = 0;
    for (char c : input.toCharArray()) {
        Base base = Base.valueOf(String.valueOf(c));
        packed = base.getPacked(packed);
    }
}
```

And your enum would look like:

```
public enum Base {

    A {
        public char getPacked(char packed) {
            return packed;
        }
    }, T {
        public char getPacked(char packed) {
            return (char) (packed | 1);
        }
    }, C {
        public char getPacked(char packed) {
            return packed;
        }
    }, G {
        public char getPacked(char packed) {
            return packed;
        }
    };

    public abstract char getPacked(char packed);
}
```

Comment: I see. I suppose I am used to having some kind of constant keyword. 

So it's sort of not possible to do this in Java then?

Comment: Yes, it's not possible to do that with arrays.  You can switch on enumerations, however, which may be of use to you in this scenario.

Comment: @maccers I have added an example of how you could use an enum to achieve the same goal.

Comment: @assylias: In your example, given that all but one implementation of `getPacked` just returned `packed`, I'd put that implementation in the base enum and override it *just* in `T`

Comment: @JonSkeet Fair point - I did it that way because I assumed each would be different in the real world (but the OP has not shown all his code so your comment might apply indeed).